# In robot framework ride GUI, how can I check the number of a specific text appear in a page?

Tags: selenium, robotframework, keyword

For example in the page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avocado_sunblotch_viroid

I like to know how many times the word fruit appeared excluding links and headers.

Comment: Have you read through any documentation or tried anything?

Comment: At [so] we expect that questions meet certain standards. Most noteably that you've put in some effort to solve the question yourself. This can take many forms, but often a [mcve] is used to showcase your issue. More information about these expectations are outlined in the [help]. When you put more time in your question you'll get better quality responses and likely a solution to your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand what you need. There is no straight forward approach to do this with ROBOT RIDE. You need to extract the text details of each paragraph first. See technical approach below.

1. Get the xpath locator for each paragraph. So, you need to know how many paragraphs.
2. Then, just calculate the count, use the GET COUNT & EVALUATE keywords (built-in keywords).

Example:

```
${text_para1}=  GET TEXT  xpath=//div[@class='mw-parser-output']//p[1]
${text_para2}=  GET TEXT  xpath=//div[@class='mw-parser-output']//p[2] #this xpath locator is example only.

${count1}= GET COUNT  ${text_para1}   fruit
${count2}= GET COUNT  ${text_para2}   fruit

${count}= EVALUATE  ${count1} + ${count2}
```

Comment: Thank you! I thought I was missing something. Your answer helped me a lot.

Comment: you are welcome.. don't forget to click accept my answer :)